# How do I query this information from a MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

My table is setup like this:

id | config_name | config_value

1 | language | English
2 | currency | $
3 | date_format | M d, Y
etc...

I'm trying to query the database to use this information as needed throughout a page. There may be 100 rows in this table, but I only need to use specific ones on a page. That's why I need to specify which one(s) I'm using. For example:

**$config->language;** would echo "English"
**$config->currency;** would echo "$", etc.

How would I set this up?

I know how to get the values and echo the same thing over and over again in a while loop:

```
$systemconfig = mysql_query("SELECT config_name, config_value FROM system_config");             

    while($configs = mysql_fetch_array( $systemconfig )) {
        echo "The value of ".$configs['config_name']."is: ".$configs['config_value'];

    } // end while
```

... but I don't want to be stuck in that loop as it cycles through all the configs in the database. That's why I would like to be able to echo the specific config values I specify throughout the page like mentioned above, ie: **$config->language**

Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: You understand that by wanting `$config->language` you imply that you want to create a 'config' object, and then just fill in the variable language inside that object with whatever value you pull from the database. Is there a problem here? Just create the object, loop through elements and use.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been trying to do but I can't get it to work. Any help on this would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is pretty straight forward, you have to walk yourself through the thought process:

- Create an object with a constructor that connects and grabs config info
- Have call the object when needed.

Here is a rough object example (you fill in the code needed):

```
<?php
class config
{
    protected $self = array();

    function __construct()  // a constructor runs on initialization of object
    {
       $q = mysql_query("SELECT config_name, config_value FROM system_config");             

        while($configs = mysql_fetch_array( $q )) {
            $this->add($configs['config_name'], $configs['config_value']);

        }
    }

    function add($key, $value){
        $this->self[$key] = $value;
    }

    function __get( $name = null ) {   // this is a getter that you call
        if(isset($this->self[$name])){ 
            return $this->self[$name];
        } 
        return false;  // this is returned if element doesn't exist
    }
}

$config = new config;
echo $config->language;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. Now what do I do in the "mysql stuff here" area? Select * from system_config...fetch array or something??

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing with objects/classes. This bit of code is the closest I've come to my solution, but I can't ever seeem to get a complete bit of code to show me what to do and get it working. I've inserted some SQL stuff that obviously doesnt work, but I don't know what else to do with this.

Comment: @user971230, I've updated the code, that should be pretty much complete with constructor and getter. Essentially I create an object that upon initialization, connects to the DB, gets all your fields, PUTS them into an array (contained in the object) then you call a `__get` function to get the elements, referenced like so `$config->language` and language is the name fetched via the `__get($name)` function.  If that name does not exist, it returns false.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you for your help thus far... one last speed bump... I'm getting unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION on the line $self = array();

Comment: @user971230, lets go to [chat], I've updated my code again, typo.

Comment: Worked EXACTLY as I have been looking for! THANK YOU! I have been trying to do this for weeks now!

Answer (score 1):

Either you fetch everything, or you have to know in advance what config values you'll be using in the page and fetch only those.

Otherwise you're stuck with having to make an auto-loading object that'll fetch/cache each configuration value as the option's accessed.

Answer (score 0):

use [mysql_fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

better way

```
function getConfig($what)
{
    $qry   = "SELECT `config_name` AS `name` , `config_value` AS `value` 
            FROM `system_config` WHERE `config_name`=$what";
    $reslt = mysql_query($qry);
    return mysql_fetch_object($result);
}

$config = getConfig('language');
while($row=$config)
{
   echo $config->name;
   echo $config->value;
}
```

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for! Only, what do I tried echo $config->language; using the example shown in your link and it doesn't echo anything.

Comment: try to debug with `var_dump($config);` and tell me what it show

Comment: If I do echo $config->$config_value, I get all the values in the table echoed. I'm trying to echo specific rows.

Comment: This looks good but I would have to do a seperate query for every single row. The suggestion offered by Jakub above sounds like what I've been trying to accomplish, but once I get into working with objects things get a little over my head.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build $config as a key=>value array with the key being the config name and the value being the config value.

Then if you insist upon using object notation you can use `extract()` in a class constructor to 'dump' the values of the $config array as class properties using the key as the variable name.